# Change scope of Azure API Mgmt Subscription

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a dozen or so subscriptions in Azure API Mgmt portal pointing to a scope of "API". But we will soon be updating to a new version, and I need to migrate these subscriptions as needed to v2. Is there a way to change the scope of an API Mgmt Subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll have available both of your APIs and let your subscribers migrate to your new version in their own time, and eventually, you'd depreciate your oldest version as you release newer versions.

Comment: ok, makes sense, but let's say I've planned something poorly, and we have installed windows apps out in the world that have a fixed subscriber id, and changing the id at any given site is prohibitively difficult. So, I can push a software update to ALL of the installations, but the config file that includes any unit's particular sub id cannot be part of that. So, short of some creative code changes, let's say that a unit's sub id is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST API do do the job, see "scope" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/subscription/update.

Comment: that looks promising but will take a little time to try before I can mark it as the answer.